# AFS filesystem volume name length

Tags: linux, filesystems, solaris, openafs

As far as I know there is/was a limitation for AFS volume name length so one can practically use 22 characters only (we use read only volumes as well so we need to fit into the 31 char limit with adding ".readonly"). Does anyone know if this limit still applies for recent OpenAFS releases and if yes, what is the reason for this limitation other than historic? I would really like to be able to use longer names.
(Already asked on superuser.com but realized it fits better here).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the limitation is still present. However, it can be seen [here](https://www.auristor.com/openafs/migrate-to-auristor/auristor-deployment-strategy).

> Volume ID name space restricted to AFS limits

And and about .readonly character limitation: [this](https://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/systems/AFS/OpenAFSRefMan/1/vos_create.html) link says, that

> The maximum length is 22 characters, which can include any
>   alphanumeric or punctuation character. By convention, periods separate
>   the fields in a name. Do not apply the .backup or .readonly extension
>   to a read/write volume name; they are reserved for the Volume Server
>   to add to the read/write name when creating those backup and read-only
>   volumes respectively.